# DropDownListFor value not setting when creating new SelectList in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Example #1 (this one works)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State.Id, Model.States)
```

I'm creating the SelectList in the controller for the first example like this.

```
var states = Repository.GetStates();
var statesSelectList = new SelectList(states, "Id", "Name");

//model.States is a SelectList
model.States = statesSelectList;
```

Example #2 (this doesn't set the selected value on load)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State.Id, new SelectList(Model.States, "Id", "Name"))
```

I'm creating the SelectList in the view for the second example, and the controller looks like this.

```
//model.States is a List<State>.
model.States = Repository.GetStates();
```

It seems there must be something simple that I'm missing.  Let me know if I need to clarify anything else.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a property to your view model:

```
private int? stateId;
public int StateId
{
    get { return stateId ?? State.Id; }
    set { stateId = value; }
}
```

Then in your Razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, new SelectList(Model.States, "Id", "Name"))
```

And finally in your controller POST action:

```
model.State = Repository.GetState(model.StateId);
```

Comment: I like your implementation, but I like Dave A's simple explanation about binding to nested objects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple, yes. Obvious no. `DropDownListFor` does not bind to nested objects like `m => m.State.Id`.

It is designed for more basic relationships like `m => m.Id`